# Nightsbridge booking calender, Send input values to a redirect page after form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple peace of code to Send input values to a redirect page after form submission.

However my skill set to complete the script is a bit too basic, i want the below script to redirect as explained below:

Herewith the form to generate the "Check in and Check out input fields:

```
<form class="form book-now-form" role="form" id="widget_booking_form" name="widget_booking_form">
    <input id="action" type="hidden" value="2" name="action"> <input id="clone_id" type="hidden" value="1111" name="bbid">
    <!--check in element-->
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="check-in">Check In</label> <!-- <input type="textfield" class="form-control" id="check-in" placeholder="12.20.2014"> -->
       <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="start-date" name="startdate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
    </div>
    <!--check out element-->
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="check-out">Check Out</label> <!-- <input type="textfield" class="form-control" id="check-out" placeholder="12.27.2014"> -->
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end-date" name="enddate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" >
    </div>
    <!--submit-->
    <div class="form-group">
       <button name="Submit" href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here with the JS used to generate the calendar and dates:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( function() {
    var dateToday = new Date();
    var dates = $("#start-date, #end-date").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+2d",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: dateToday,
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
          var option = this.id == "start-date" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
          instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
          date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
          dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

But with the above code, the script generates the input values (Dates) incorrectly along with all input Variables.

So i need to now have the page redirect to nightsbrige's bridge (https://www.nightsbridge.co.za/bridge/book) with the following Variable format

```
?action=2&bbid=1111&startdate=2018-05-08&enddate=2018-05-09
```

and not `?action=2&bbid=1111&startdate=05%2F16%2F2018&enddate=05%2F23%2F2018&Submit=`

any assistance will greatly be appreciated :) once this code is fixed it will be free to use.

Comment: Go read the documentation of your datepicker library, how to specify in what format you want the value returned.

Comment: you need to add the `action=redirectpagelocation` and `method=post/get` attribute to the form tag

Comment: Thank you for your replies, as suggested i have managed to implement the `action=redirectpagelocation` and `method=get`

Comment: But now another problem has me still stuck to complete the script, the redirect input values are correctly display now but the date format is not accepted by the end processing bridge.

Here is the output result: `?action=2&bbid=1111&startdate=2018%2F05%2F09&enddate=2018%2F05%2F11`

And this is what it needs to be: `?action=2&bbid=1111&startdate=2018-05-09&enddate=2018-05-11`

I have tried the following but its still not working:
`$('#start-date').val( $('#start-date').val().replace(/\//g, '') );`
`$('#end-date').val( $('#end-date').val().replace(/\//g, '') );`